# Accessing host's host:port from Docker container in OSX

Tags: macos, docker

This question may be similar to other questions already answered, but I could not find any that is specific to OSX.

I'm new to Docker.  I'm using Docker Version 1.12.1-beta25 (build: 11807) native support for OSX.  I wanted to install a Docker Bamboo remote agent, following the instructions at https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/getting-started-with-docker-and-bamboo-687213473.html.  My Bamboo server is running on the host.

When running the Docker container with `docker run -e HOME=/root/ -e BAMBOO_SERVER=http://hostname:port/bamboo -i -t atlassian/bamboo-java-agent:latest`, it failed with *Connecting to http://hostname:port/bamboo refused*

The problem seems to be that the container could not access the host's  http://hostname:port/bamboo.  What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Did you literally type out `hostname:port`? If not, you can always look over the output of `docker inspect your_container_id` (not literally!) to see which ports are being exposed to the host.

Comment: Of course not literal `hostname:port`!  What am I supposed to see in the output of `docker inspect` if a port is open?

Comment: you'd want to look under `"HostConfig"` > `"NetworkSettings"` > `"Ports"` for a list of port mappings.

Comment: @Jules that field is empty.  Hmmm....so I think there must be a parameter I have to specify to get the host's port in there.  What is it?

Comment: At least one problem is that the run command doesn't publish ports. You need also to specify `-p <host port>:<container port>`.

Comment: @ronkot, I tried with `-p 8085:9000` but got an error _bind for 0.0.0.0:8085 failed: port is already allocated_.  The Bamboo server on the host is running and listening on the port 8085.  *confused*

Comment: @His, I don't know how Bamboo works, but fast skimming through the link you provided shows that maybe the port you need to open on you _container side_ is port 8085. Thus, open that port on container side and choose any free port from host side: `-p 56789:8085`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use http://172.17.0.1:port to find the host from the container. You find this address with docker inspect 'name'.

Or, you can use -p hostPort:containerPort in the docker run command and yse http://localhost:containerPort as Banboo_server

Comment: The `172.17.x.x` subnet is not necessarily correct here. That's totally dependent on OP's network, Docker, and server configuration.

Comment: I tried with `-p 8085:9000` but got an error bind for 0.0.0.0:8085 failed: port is already allocated. The Bamboo server on the host is running and listening on the port 8085.

Comment: docker inspect 'name' doesn't show any host IP addresses for me